# Maximum number of Quartz nodes in a cluster?

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

I'm working on a system that uses Quartz in cluster-mode and we currently have 18 servers in the cluster. The problem we're facing is that some jobs get executed twice and rarely some jobs get 'stuck' in ACQUIRED state or other weird issues.

I read that the documentation says:

*The scheduler makes use of a **cluster-wide lock**, a pattern that degrades performance as you add more nodes (when going beyond about **three nodes** - depending upon your database's capabilities, etc.).*

We have lots of warnings like this:

*[WARN  o.s.s.q.LocalDataSourceJobStore - This scheduler instance (xxx) is still active but was recovered by another instance in the cluster.  This may cause inconsistent behavior.*

**We have synchronized the clock on all machines in the cluster.**

My questions are:

- Does someone else have a big cluster of Quartz instances and experiences similar problems?
- Is Quartz really limited to maximum 3-4 machines per cluster?
- Are there any work-arounds for this?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: You may want to check http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/faq#FAQ-springCommit for the problem with ACQUIRED state and other weird issues you may be experiencing.